# height of the Navbar increase after re sizing to mobile size and resetting back again to desktop size

Tags: css, html, nav

Hi guys i have a very weird problem. If you can see my navbar when resized to mobile size and click in drop down and again make it normal desktop size there is an increase in the navbar height. I wanted a horizontal justified menu for this i used

```
.menu_container>ul:after{
content: "";
padding-left: 100%;
visibility: hidden;
/* do not use float:left but the display:inline-block below!!! */
display: inline-block;
}
```

If I removed the content:"", it works fine but the justification of the menu goes off

[**This is my fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz58y/)

Also attached screenshot for your reference
[image: Original height of navbar]

[image: After resizing, click on dropdown and back to desktop size]

Comment: check my answer for the solution. It's because of the height: auto present in the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz58y/1/)**

Its because of `height: auto;` present in

```
#hidden_menu_collapser:checked + ul {
height: auto;
min-height: 40px;
max-height: 2999px;
background-color: 
#FFF;
}
```

You need update the `height:auto;` to `height: 44px !important;`  and update it in desktop media query, so that that extra space is removed.

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
     #hidden_menu_collapser:checked + ul {
       min-height: 40px;
       max-height: 2999px;
       background-color: #FFF;
       height: 44px !important;
    }
   }
```

You can just copy paste the above css to your file and it will work

Comment: that did it. You are a star dude. Been wrecking my brains over this

Comment: dude i need another problem by second level menu with grey background is not justifying like the first level, I have used the same concept but its floating on left. This is my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bz58y/2/

Comment: .menu_container>ul>li {
position: relative;
padding: 8px 17px;
background: inherit;
margin: 0; 
} this make it align properly